# dynamically changing CSS Using jQuery on $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a template with the page header which margin changes depending on the page i'm in.

my template is something like:

```
<div class="header"> Title - Menu </div>
```

that header is equal in every single page, except the margin-bottom

i have this jQuery code which works right with one problem (this is in-line code at the top of the each page) :

```
$(function () {  $(".header").css("margin-bottom","0px"); });
```

or

```
$(function () {  $(".header").css("margin-bottom","30px"); });
```

the problem is i see the page with margin of the template, and then it changes the margin dynamically. it looks bad, at refresh it have a blank space between header and body and then disappears 1 second later.

Comment: Why don't you just give the `header` a particular `class` to set the `margin-bottom` accordingly? Keep everything in just `CSS`.

Comment: Anyway... You have missing `)` in both your scripts.

Comment: yes was missing, but you understood my problem, thank you anyway! problem solved with first answer

Comment: *was missing here, not in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into FUOC:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content.

Assuming your CSS is being declared in your header, if you redefine it with jQuery after the document loads of course you'll see a flash of style changing. This is because, while your CSS is being rendered while the DOM populates, your jQuery is firing only after the **entire** page is done.

There's really no need to do this in jQuery. If you want to keep the changes inline, simply add something like this after your main stylesheet and adjust it for each page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .header {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

Of course, if jQuery is a requirement for this, using an IIFE function will work.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Please remember to check-off an answer as your solution if it solved your problem. SO community loves to help, but they love their internet points too :)

Comment: yes, sure, i'm new here sorry. i have more one problem here to remove all the js in-line code. i had this $("#menu-posts").addClass("active-button"); to select a button, that is obviously different in each page, there is something in css to do this without replicate code? and there is not wrong with the  in-line css (in this example) or it is bad programming? thank you

Comment: No problem, welcome to Stack Overflow! Unless you're adding/removing a class on an action (on click or hover, for example), I'd recommend not using jQuery for any styling. If you're already using my method on a page-to-page basis to adjust the `.header` margin, I would also use that area to declare other styles you plan to only use for the individual page.

Comment: thanks! beside the downvotes, people are nice here, this encourage new people to continue and learn srsly :). the jQuery code: $("#menu-posts").addClass("active-button"); is for style only, when the page loads the button is pressed. i would use the CSS area but i just don't know how, i have on page.cs
.subm li.active-button > a,
.subm li.active-button > a:hover,
.subm li.active-button > a:focus {
...
}
i just don't want to repeat that code every page on different buttons something like addClass css version was better lol

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are changing the margin on page load. I.e. inside $(function(){}). Therefore your css margin code runs only after the whole page has loaded. That could take some time.

So there are couple of things you could do. 1. Use script tag right after your div tag

```
<div class="header"> Title - Menu </div>
<script>
   $(".header").css("margin-bottom","0px");
</script>
```

This assumes jquery has loaded (may be above body tags?)

This is however not a general practice. 2. Second option would be to assign styles directly to the div

```
<div class="header" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"> Title - Menu </div>
```

Comment: i can't change the style of the header because its a template to all the pages, i ll use the first answer it keeps me away from using in-line jquery code too. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer a solution where you render the header with two different CSS styles on the server side. That would avoid the issue altogether.

If nothing else works, you can force the browser to evaluate the script earlier while it's still parsing the page:

```
<div class="header"> Title - Menu </div>
<script>$(".header").css("margin-bottom","0px");</script>
```

That forces the browser to evaluate the script right after the `div` has been created but before the next element is considered. Note that the DOM won't be complete at this time. It's guaranteed that the `div` exists but things after those two lines might or might not be there.

Comment: `$(function () {});` will wait until the document is ready, no matter where you put it in the page.

Comment: And there's a missing `)` there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('.header').css("margin-bottom","0px"); });
```